# 0-10V control signal for valve actuator from -10/10V DAC

Tags: control-system, actuator, industrial

I'm trying to control a valve actuator (24VAC power) that uses a 0-10V voltage input signal which only uses one wire, with a USB multifunction board which has a +-10V DAC control output which uses two wires, "DAC0" and "DAC0 Return". Note that I am only using the "DAC0" line since the device only has one input line. The valve actuator input impedance is 100K ohms, and the DAC can output +-2mA at <0.2ohm impedance. I'm thinking that this should work, but it doesn't. I've also tried an eternally powered 0-10V isolation module, which does generate the desired signal voltage corresponding to my DAC output signal voltage, but this still does not control the actuator properly.

Any ideas? It's definitely possible that the actuator is not functioning properly, since it's pre-owned.

VA7800 Valve Actuator Spec Sheet:
https://cgproducts.johnsoncontrols.com/MET_PDF/12011474.pdf

DT9812-10V Multifunction Board Spec Sheet:
[https://pim-resources.coleparmer.com/instruction-manual/18801-20-25-30um.pdf][1]](https://pim-resources.coleparmer.com/instruction-manual/18801-20-25-30um.pdf%5D%5B1%5D) - page 161

Comment: Make sure all the switches are in the correct positions for the actuator configuration and the appropriate power is applied. Just try applying a voltage to the actuator from a battery or isolated power supply to see if it is working (measure the voltage).

Comment: "only one control line"  Huh?  figure 3 shows two control lines.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany good thought. Switches appear to be in the correct positions. I've tried applying a voltage from a few other sources, none of which have done anything.

Comment: @Jasen I'm trying to use the actuator in the "proportional" voltage control mode (top left of Figure 3). There are 4 connections to be made, depending on the control mode. Connections 1 and 2 are 24VAC power. Connections 3 is control voltage input. Connection 4 is an output for position feedback to the controller.

Comment: ah, now I see.  the upside down T (terminal 2)  is the cricuit common, connect the 10VDC return wire wire to that and the send wire to the input.